# Regex match when substring present

Tags: regex

I would like to use regex to match numbers if a substring is present, but without matching the substring. Hence,

```
2-4 foo
foo 4-6
bar 8
```

should match

```
2, 4
4, 6
```

I currently have

```
(\d{0,}\.?\d{1,})
```

which returns the numbers (int or float). Using

```
(\d{0,}\.?\d{1,}(?=\sfoo))
```

only matches `4`, rather than `2` and `4`. I also tried a lookahead

```
^(?=.*?\bfoo\b)(\d{0,}\.?\d{1,})
```

but that matches the `2` only.

*edited typo

Comment: *but that matches the 4 only.* No it should match the `2` only.

Comment: shouldn't `\.?` be `\-?`  (or `-?` since not in []) or just `.?`?

Comment: Sorry @iBug, yes you are absolutely correct.

Comment: You need to specify the regex flavor. Else, the suggested pattern might either be suboptimal or just won't work. See `(?<=\bfoo\b.*)\d*\.?\d+|\d*\.?\d+(?=.*?\bfoo\b)` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/ayVlIX/1).

Comment: This doesn't seem like a good application of regex. Better build the substring detection logic with other techniques available, then apply regex to extract numbers.

Comment: @iBug - interesting. I'm new to using regex (can you tell). So it would be to do (in Python) 

if 'foo' in string: 
    apply regex to get numbers

Comment: Yes, in Python, `if 'foo' in text: print(re.findall(r'\d*\.?\d+', text))` or `if re.search(r'\bfoo\b', text): print(re.findall(r'\d*\.?\d+', text))`

Comment: I see. I thought I could do it all with a regex command. Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With engines that support infinite width lookbehind patterns, you can use

```js
(?<=\bfoo\b.*)\d*\.?\d+|\d*\.?\d+(?=.*?\bfoo\b)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ayVlIX/1). It matches any zero or more digits followed with an optional dot and then one or more digits when either preceded with a whole word `foo` (not necessarily immediately) or when followed with `foo` whole word somewhere to the right.

When you have access to the code, you can simply check for the word presence in the text and then extract all the match occurrences. In Python, you could use

```py
if 'foo' in text:
    print(re.findall(r'\d*\.?\d+', text))
# Or, if you need to make sure the foo is a whole word:
if re.search(r'\bfoo\b', text):
    print(re.findall(r'\d*\.?\d+', text))
```